# Decoded a pdf stream to render pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I am trying to render a pdf source stream to a visual pdf in HTML.   I have the stream source data but I not sure how to decoded/render this to a visual pdf.  Code looks something like this.

```
    %PDF-1.3
    %����
    1 0 obj 
    <<
    /Pages 2 0 R
    /Type /Catalog
    >>
    endobj 
    2 0 obj 
    <<
    /Kids [3 0 R]
    /Count 1
    /Type /Pages
    >>
    endobj 
    3 0 obj 
    ...
    
stream
��E�+&z5�C8̔Ec8�<�3��~<�Ǚ�(R�HBSfq�n!����Q�gf@B����#��8�r8)��>ϳ8�RC8)">�>�UL&�P�P�T��aSp�S
��MR��i����%�:�Qѝ�����fv����i�3;Tgw3�9tgk3���*3�Y�Fv����Q��ׯ4���9��� �9���y�9�l�G��N�����D~��O�S����{���o��>���=#��x��g�<q��<�a)��D�����?'�"?�8��   �q����?���>�����=�����x�����]qǒ���H��r����sۂ#�48H�憍F{��y���k���C�g�^]v���Z�=(��a~����}U\�$*���Ǵq��?�"{b�K�q�>>?��D�b��^5�׸���ǯ�-y����;]�G����=�~?�0?������D`������oI�"?Y��a�<?������,]*_�O��?����g��ǧ�����g��c��
-�9����C�K���/��������^z}z��]}}z�9�Z��g?��W�����j�Q������1����������ӵ/U�n��]�y��"�ϵ�SJ�5�v��f3��k�t�joJ����+�����+b�����A�S60A��
�b�-o��Aȷc�ȰW��`�b�A��8��lr,ȹ������au���l�)�i��������?��k�
    
    <<
    /Info 9 0 R
    /Root 1 0 R
    /Size 10
    >>
    startxref
    43084
    %%EOF
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a render engine for this... and I doubt you will be able to program this, so search the internet for "PDF Reader" or "PDF Viewer".

Comment: If you want to implement your own renderer, you should start by studying the pdf specification, ISO 32000-2 or at least ISO 32000-1.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz not trying to program this from scratch, however, Chrome has its own engine I believe (or it may be an open source), isn't there a way to extend Chrome pdf engine and pass this to it to render it?

Comment: @mkl not trying to create my own but extending some open source for it.

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out that if I save that file as ext .pdf.  any browser, pdf reader will be able to read it.  No need to created your own render engine.